# Error reading file from disk: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './database.json

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js

Im doing some tests, where I'm testing the POST routes,I think the test are written out fine, however now i'm getting an error which says

"Error reading file from disk: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './database.json"

```
describe ("POST /post methods",() => {
  it("should get /post ",(done)=>{
     const incomingRequest = {
        name: "charanjit",
        content: "im posting",
        gif: ""

     };
    chai.request(server)
    .post("/posts")
    .send(incomingRequest)
    .end(function (err, res) {
      expect(res).to.have.status(500)
      done()
    });


    
    
    


})
it("should get /comments ",(done)=>{
    const commente = {
       comment: "hi omg"

    };
    chai.request(server)
    .post("/comments")
    .send(commente)
    .end(function (err, res) {
      expect(res).to.have.status(200)
      done()
    });


 })
   it("should get /emoji ",(done)=>{
    const commente = {
    comment: "hi omg"

 };
 chai.request(server)
 .post("/comments")
 .send(commente)
 .end(function (err, res) {
  expect(res).to.have.status(200)
  done()
  });
```

These are the test i've wriiten.
and this is what I wrote on the server side code.

```
 server.post("/posts", (req, res) => {
  const incomingRequest = req.body;
  if (isValidPost(incomingRequest)) {
    const post = {
   name: incomingRequest.name.toString(),
   content: incomingRequest.content.toString(),
   giph: incomingRequest.gif.toString(),
   date: new Date(),
   likes: 0,
   dislikes: 0,
   laughs: 0,
   comments: [],
  };

  //read the file
  fs.readFile("./database.json", "utf8", (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(`Error reading file from disk: ${err}`);
  } else {
    //parse JSON string to JSON object
    const postsData = JSON.parse(data);
    post.id = postsData.length + 1;
    postsData.push(post);

    fs.writeFile(
      "./database.json",
      JSON.stringify(postsData, null, 4),
      (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(`Error writing file: ${err}`);
        }
      }
    );
    res.status(201).send(post);
    }
  });
 }    else {
  res.status(422).send("Name and content required!");
 }
});

  //POST ROUTE - EMOJIS

  server.post("/emojis", (req, res) => {
 const incomingRequest = req.body;
 const emoji = incomingRequest.emoji;
 const id = incomingRequest.id;

 fs.readFile("./database.json", "utf8", (err, data) => {
 if (err) {
   console.log(`Error reading file from disk: ${err}`);
 } else {
  const postsData = JSON.parse(data);
  if (emoji === "fa-thumbs-up") {
    postsData[id - 1].likes++;
  }
  if (emoji === "fa-thumbs-down") {
    postsData[id - 1].dislikes++;
  }
  if (emoji === "fa-laugh-squint") {
    postsData[id - 1].laughs++;
  }

  fs.writeFile(
    "./database.json",
    JSON.stringify(postsData, null, 4),
    (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(`Error writing file: ${err}`);
      }
    }
    );
  }
   res.status(201).json([emoji, id]);
  });
 });

  server.post("/comments", (req, res) => {
  const incomingRequest = req.body;
  const comment = incomingRequest.comment;
  const id = incomingRequest.id;

fs.readFile("./database.json", "utf8", (err, data) => {
 if (err) {
   console.log(`Error reading file from disk: ${err}`);
  } else {
  const postsData = JSON.parse(data);
  postsData[id - 1].comments.push(comment);
  fs.writeFile(
    "./database.json",
    JSON.stringify(postsData, null, 4),
    (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(`Error writing file: ${err}`);
        }
      }
     );
   }
   res.status(201).send(comment);
    });
  });
```

What is causing this error, do I need to write a test which will access the database, im abit confused and how would I go about doing that?

the project structure file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HV4EE.png)

Comment: The code can't reach the file. How is your project structure?

Comment: we have a functional project structure, how would I require the database from the test files?

Comment: Is the `database.json` in the same folder as your test file?

Comment: no, its outside of it, the database.json file is in the server file, whereas my test.js file is in the test folder

Comment: So you have to navigate to your file. Uring `../` you can go to parent directory. If you post the folder structure and where is each one (`database.json` and your test file) I can post and answer with the solution.

Comment: Hi, so i posted the picture of the project structure file, so I'm working in the test folder (test.js) and my server.js code is in the server folder along with the database and package.json file

Comment: Answered. If I've not read bad the project structure the code should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your project structure you only need go one folder up and then go to `server` folder.

This code will work:

```js
fs.readFile("../server/database.json", "utf8", (err, data) => {
  // ...
}
```

Note that you have to use `../` to go to parent directory. Then you can reach the document inside `server/` called `database.json`.